# Apache Camel route, pull a value from a BSON document to put in an http connection string

Tags: apache-camel, bson

I'm pulling a document from a MongoDB and want to take the value of startTime and add it as a connection parameter to an http url string.

The document looks like this:

```
Document{{_id=6110593a2d79803d4ebf2b83, startTime=1585009140000}}
```

I'm using projection to get only the field I need. I can log the value using jsonpath. But how to I get the value in a way I can cleanly add it to the http url?

```
from("timer:PingTimer?fixedRate=true&period=15000")
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.SORT_BY).constant(Sorts.descending("startTime"))
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.FIELDS_PROJECTION).constant(Projections.include("startTime"))
.setBody().constant("{}")
.to("mongodb:mongo?database={{spring.data.mongodb.database}}&collection=one_min&operation=findOneByQuery")
.log("Body ${body}")
.toD("https://this.that/api/markets/USD?resolution=60&start_time=" 
        //How do I get the value of startTime in here? 
        )
.setBody().jsonpath("$.startTime")  // This gets the value
;
```

[Edit]

Is this advisable?

```
.setHeader("test").jsonpath("$.startTime")
.toD("https://this.that/api/markets/USD?resolution=60&start_time=" + "${headers.test}")
```

Comment: Add query parameters to `CamelHttpQuery` header instead of Endpoint URI. Camel uses Endpoint URI to configure the endpoint and `CamelHttpQuery` to add query parameters to the request. In Java DSL you can get the header name from `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY` as well if you want to avoid typing the header name manually. This can be a bit cleaner as with authentication and all the endpoint URI can get rather lenghty.